# Slam to path planning

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to know what way to implement a complete Slam test. I currently have a Omron OS32C laser scanner mounted on a AGV. Please suggest me the approach to create a map from a laser scanner and then making my AGV follow a specific path.
I know that gmapping package can be used to create the map from laser scanner readings. Still I want to know whether there is a full stack implementation someone has carried out and can suggest me.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269564/slam-to-path-planning/) by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2017-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can take a look at the [ROS Navigation Stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) which offers several options for global and local planners plus plenty of tutorials for getting up to speed!

---

Originally posted by [juanlu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29661/juanlu/) with karma: 189 on 2017-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2017-08-25**:
Thanks. You are right.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-04**:
@Harsh2308 if this answered your question, then you should mark it as correct.